# Typesetting a subset of the MLA format (with example tex/sty)

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, margins, biblatex-mla

My professor has specific tweaks he wants me to do, especially with the citations. However, in attempting to make those tweaks, it seems something broke in Ryan Aycock's old MLA style, if it was even working to begin with. The symptoms:

- my footer is consistently too large, by about a half of an inch
- <strike>the font size, set in the \documentclass options to 12pt, is not 12pt (1/6in or 4.233mm), it's 9pt (1/8", or 3.125mm).</strike>
- There is space between two of the bibliography entries

Here is the [example pdf](https://ptpb.pw/Kd_N), and a minimal working example:

[sample document file](https://ptpb.pw/kppe),
[style file](https://ptpb.pw/Lk0e),
[sample bibliography](https://ptpb.pw/4cLC),
[BBX File](https://ptpb.pw/Tcvh),
[CBX file](https://ptpb.pw/r6Rh)

I have scoured the internet trying to figure this out, but the geometry docs are a bit confusing and at this point I just don't have time to keep trying to work this out. Any suggestions?

Edit: I was measuring my fonts incorrectly (didn't count descenders). The other issues remain.

Comment: The space between the bibliography entries is because your `.bib` item `RightInTwo` is of type `misc` which `biblatex-mla` doesn't recognize as a proper entry type. So you need to reclassify it (e.g. `unpublished`) and it will appear correctly in the bibliography.  The style file is a mess.  I would remove all margin/geometry related code from it entirely and just use `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}`.  In a package you should use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`.  Also you should use `newtxtext` instead of `mathptmx`.

Comment: Also, your sample document has no footer information, so I assume you mean "header" in the first problem?

Comment: I actually meant margin. The text halts more than an inch from the bottom. Thanks so much for the tips. I've tried to jump headlong into tex this semester, doing every project and paper in it, but I'm still very new and it's a complicated system to get used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style file you're using is really a bit of a mess.  To make things easier to understand, I've included all of it in the test document. I've deleted all of the margins related code and replaced it with simply `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}`.  I've also replaced the `mathptmx` package with `newtxtext` for an up to date Times Roman font. If you also need math support, also load `newtxmath`.

If you want to fix the package, replace all the `\usepackage` commands with `\RequirePackage`.  The `hyperref` package likes to be loaded after most other packages, so you should load it last in the package and load your package after any other document packages you load.

The bibliography problem is solved by changing the entry type of your `RightInTwo` entry from `misc` to something else. I used `unpublished` as an example.

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk

\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage{my-mla-pkg}

%%%%% This is the code that is currently in the package %%%%
\usepackage{newtxtext}   % Times New Roman font
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}    
\doublespacing

%
%   Last name and page number on every page
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{norule}{ %
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
  \fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagestyle{norule}

\usepackage{url}

% Bibliography/Works Cited Settings
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes, xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=my-mla,citestyle=my-mla,annotation=true]{biblatex}

% Hyperref
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref} % hyperref should be loaded last.

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

%   MLA environment
\newenvironment{mla}[6]{ \setcounter{page}{1} \fancyhead[RO]{#2{}\thepage}
  \raggedright #1\ #2 \\
  Professor #3 \\
  #4 \\
  #5 \\
  \centering #6 \\
  \frenchspacing\raggedright\setlength{\parindent}{.5in}{ \nonfrenchspacing} }

%
%   Block quote environment
%
\newenvironment{blocks}{\begin{quote} \linespread{1} \small
    \normalsize}{\end{quote} \linespread{2} \small \normalsize}
\newenvironment{blockm}{\begin{quotation} \linespread{1} \small
    \normalsize}{\end{quotation} \linespread{2} \small \normalsize}

%  
%   Russ Ault's mla quote environment
%   
\newenvironment{mlaquote}{\list{}{\leftmargin=1in}\item[]}{\endlist}
\newenvironment{mlaquotation}{\list{}{\leftmargin=1in}\item[]\parindent=0.5in}{\endlist}

%%%% End of package code


\newcommand{\firstname}{m00n }
\newcommand{\lastname}{aspookyghosty }
\newcommand{\prof}{my english prof}
\newcommand{\class}{english class}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
% enable annotations
\usepackage{blindtext}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\centering Works Cited}
\author{\firstname \lastname}
\addbibresource{frankencrit-citations.bib}


\begin{document}
\begin{mla}{\firstname}{\lastname}{\prof}{\class}{\today}{MinimalWorkingExample}
  This is a minimal working example.
  \Blindtext
  \nocite{*}
  \newpage
  \printbibliography
\end{mla}
\end{document}
```

[image: Acrobat image]

[image: bib fragment]

Comment: Ok, this works much better. However, when I print it as you have, every margin is 1/4" larger than it should be. I figured it was from the text sizing stuff, so I hardcoded the paper and text sizes into the \require[opts]{geometry} call. Now my only problem is the bottom margin, which is still that 1/4" off. Again, thanks so much, that looks awesome

Comment: @ChrisCarriganBrolly Your printing problem is likely because your PDF previewer is shrinking the page. The settings in the document give you exactly 1 inch margins (as the screenshot from Acrobat shows). Because you are using `\doublespacing` you will never get the bottom of the text to match the bottom margin. If you add `\singlespacing` to your test document you will see that the text lines up at exactly 1 inch/

Comment: I am not talking about my print preview, though. I am talking about an actually printed document. With `\RequirePackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in,textwidth=6.5in,textheight=9in,margin=1in]{geometry}` I get perfect printing, except for the bottom--but you've just cleared that up. Again, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @ChrisCarriganBrolly Yes, I understand, but many previewers have an option "Shrink page to fit" when printing, which can cause this behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? When I printed it without that line above the margins [this](https://photos.app.goo.gl/oEzhiwh3ez4sk9dB3) is what I got, a full 1/8" off (I was wrong when I said 1/4", apologies). It's fixed now, so at this point it's just my curiosity left, you've been great.

Comment: @ChrisCarriganBrolly Just out of curiosity, can you post a link to the PDF that prints *incorrectly*?

Comment: I overwrote it, and am unable to get it to go back to what it was doing before. So whatever it was, some kind of ethereal screw up of mine I'm sure, it's gone now. Thanks again for all the help and for following up with me.